# combobox generates dynamic fields

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i have a combobox to choose the the number of adults

```
<select name="adult_no" id="adult_no">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
  </select>
```

how can i generate dynamically fields for the adult name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, I think you want to create a number of text `input` elements, corresponding to the number selected in the `select`. If that's correct then you could do something like this:

```
$("#adult_no").change(function() {
    var example = $("#example");
    example.empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.value; i++) {
        example.append($("<input type='text'>"));   
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CDp8t/3/). Obviously that's unlikely to be perfect (you probably, for example, want to give the new `input` elements names or IDs), but it should be enough to get you started.